# How to make columns optional on temporary table used as stored procedure input?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have been working to replace a loop-based email sending process with a set-based process. The goal is to be able to easily select into a temporary table and then call the mail-sending procedure, thus enabling me to rapidly create new notification regimes.

FYI, this is for PowerCampus, a student information system. It has limited built-in email notifications for a small set of events. The vendor's code uses dynamic SQL to call one sproc and get the new `MESSAGEID` key back, then calls another sproc for each recipient, inputting the `MESSAGEID` as one of the parameters.

Beyond the built-in email notifications, the product also has a flexible table called Scheduled Actions (`ACTIONSCHEDULE`) with WYSIWG triggers that automatically place the actions. An Outlook mail merge can then be run against the actions and the actions marked as complete. My goal is to have an SQL job send the emails instead, then mark actions completed if the email was successfully sent.

I have a working solution, but I really wanted some of my columns to be optional to make it easier to code new notifications jobs. Here's my stored procedure. The part that doesn't work is noted as `--BEGIN part that doesn't work!` and `--END part that doesn't work!`.

It seems that I cannot add a column, then select that column inside the same stored procedure by name. However, `SELECT * FROM #Messages` works and includes the new column. Why does one work but not the other? How can I make some columns optional while ignoring any extra columns the caller might input?

Also feel free to recommend an entirely different approach, whilst understanding that I cannot change the vendor's database structure.

```
-- =============================================
-- Description: Sends an email via the MessageQueue table and related tables. Set-based instead of using a loop. Adds MySchool header, footer, and optionally body styling.
--              Requires #Messages table to already exist with the columns specified below.
--              #Messages will be de-duplicated. Messages where a [to] email can't be found will be deleted.
--              The output is a similarly constructed table of messages sent along with the MESSAGEIDs.
--              Depends on MySchool custom functions Get_MySchoolEmail and Get_AltEmail.
--
-- TODO:    Replace XACT_ABORT with TRY/CATCH.
--          Add validation of PEOPLE_CODE_ID's.
--          Find a way to make optional columns actually optionally.
--
-- Usage: Select some emails into #Messages table as shown above. Then EXEC [dbo].[MySchool_SP_SendEmails].
--        People Code Id's can be used instead of actual email addresses.
--        Future: Columns marked with 'O' are optional columns that do not need to exist.
/*
    CREATE TABLE #Messages (
        [from] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL           --an email address
O       ,[fromId] NVARCHAR(10) NULL             --sender People Code Id
O       ,[to] NVARCHAR(255) NULL                --an email address. If NULL, will be automatically supplied from toId.
        ,[toId] NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL           --recipient People Code Id
        ,[toTypeFlag] SMALLINT NOT NULL         --Flag 0/1 to control which email to select for [to]. 0 = Campus address, 1 = Alternate address.
O       ,[cc] NVARCHAR(255) NULL                --an email address. If NULL, will be automatically supplied from ccId.
O       ,[ccId] NVARCHAR(10) NULL               --cc recipient People Code Id
O       ,[bcc] NVARCHAR(255) NULL               --an email address. If NULL, will be automatically supplied from bccId.
O       ,[bccId] NVARCHAR(10) NULL              --bcc recipient People Code Id
        ,[subject] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL       --email subject line
        ,[body] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL          --email body (HTML ok)
        ,[formatBodyFlag] SMALLINT NOT NULL     --Flag 0/1 to indicate whether body should be wrapped with styling
O       ,[uniqueKey] NVARCHAR(255) NULL UNIQUE  --Can be used by caller to compare input and output rows. Suggest using [ACTIONSCHEDULE].[UNIQUE_KEY] for this purpose.
        );

    INSERT INTO #Messages
    VALUES
        ('selfservice@MySchool.edu'
            ,NULL
            ,NULL
            ,'P000123456'
            ,0
            ,'someone@gmail.com'
            ,NULL
            ,NULL
            ,NULL
            ,'Test Email 1'
            ,'This is a test of the stored procedure [dbo].[MySchool_SP_SendEmails].'
            ,1)
        ,('selfservice@MySchool.edu'
            ,NULL
            ,'someone@MySchool.edu'
            ,'P000123456'
            ,0
            ,NULL
            ,'P000234567'
            ,NULL
            ,NULL
            ,'Test Email 2'
            ,'This is a test of the stored procedure [dbo].[MySchool_SP_SendEmails].'
            ,1);

    EXEC [dbo].[MySchool_SP_SendEmails]
*/
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySchool_SP_SendEmails]

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON; --Stop on all errors.

    DECLARE @Today datetime = dbo.fnMakeDate(getdate())
    DECLARE @Now datetime = dbo.fnMakeTime(getdate())

    CREATE TABLE #MessagesStrict (
        [msKey] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY        --Identity key used internally by the procedure
        ,[from] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL          --an email address
        ,[fromId] NVARCHAR(10) NULL             --sender People Code Id
        ,[to] NVARCHAR(255) NULL                --an email address. If NULL, will be automatically supplied from toId.
        ,[toId] NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL           --recipient People Code Id
        ,[toTypeFlag] SMALLINT NOT NULL         --Flag 0/1 to control which email to select for [to]. 0 = Campus address, 1 = Alternate address.
        ,[cc] NVARCHAR(255) NULL                --an email address. If NULL, will be automatically supplied from ccId.
        ,[ccId] NVARCHAR(10) NULL               --cc recipient People Code Id
        ,[bcc] NVARCHAR(255) NULL               --an email address. If NULL, will be automatically supplied from bccId.
        ,[bccId] NVARCHAR(10) NULL              --bcc recipient People Code Id
        ,[subject] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL       --email subject line
        ,[body] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL          --email body (HTML ok)
        ,[formatBodyFlag] SMALLINT NOT NULL     --Flag 0/1 to indicate whether body should be wrapped with styling
        ,[uniqueKey] NVARCHAR(255) NULL UNIQUE  --Can be used by caller to compare input and output rows. Suggest using [ACTIONSCHEDULE].[UNIQUE_KEY] for this purpose.
        ,[MESSAGEID] INT NULL                   --Will be used later to link MESSAGEQUE to MESSAGERECIPIENTS
        );

    --BEGIN part that doesn't work! 
    --Add optional columns
    IF 'fromId' NOT IN (SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Messages'))
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE #Messages
        ADD [fromId] NVARCHAR(255) NULL
    END;

    IF 'to' NOT IN (SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Messages'))
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE #Messages
        ADD [to] NVARCHAR(255) NULL
    END;

    IF 'cc' NOT IN (SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Messages'))
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE #Messages
        ADD [cc] NVARCHAR(255) NULL
    END;

    IF 'ccId' NOT IN (SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Messages'))
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE #Messages
        ADD [ccId] NVARCHAR(255) NULL
    END;

    IF 'bcc' NOT IN (SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Messages'))
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE #Messages
        ADD [bcc] NVARCHAR(255) NULL
    END;

    IF 'bccId' NOT IN (SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Messages'))
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE #Messages
        ADD [bccId] NVARCHAR(255) NULL
    END;

    IF 'uniqueKey' NOT IN (SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Messages'))
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE #Messages
        ADD [uniqueKey] NVARCHAR(255) NULL UNIQUE
    END;
    --END part that doesn't work!

    --Basic validation. Wasteful, but we're not expecting to run massive mailings.
    INSERT INTO #MessagesStrict (
        [from]
        ,[fromId]
        ,[to]
        ,[toId]
        ,[toTypeFlag]
        ,[cc]
        ,[ccId]
        ,[bcc]
        ,[bccId]
        ,[subject]
        ,[body]
        ,[formatBodyFlag]
        ,[uniqueKey]
        )
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [from]
        ,[fromId]
        ,[to]
        ,[toId]
        ,[toTypeFlag]
        ,[cc]
        ,[ccId]
        ,[bcc]
        ,[bccId]
        ,[subject]
        ,[body]
        ,[formatBodyFlag]
        ,[uniqueKey]
    FROM #Messages; --Input table

    BEGIN TRAN MySchool_SP_SendEmails

        --Supply [to] campus addresses
        UPDATE #MessagesStrict
        SET [to] = [dbo].[Get_MySchoolEmail]([toId])
        WHERE [to] IS NULL
            AND [toTypeFlag] = 0;

        --Supply [to] secondary addresses
        UPDATE #MessagesStrict
        SET [to] = [dbo].[Get_AltEmail]([toId])
        WHERE [to] IS NULL
            AND [toTypeFlag] = 1;

        --Delete messages where correct address couldn't be found
        DELETE FROM #MessagesStrict
        WHERE [to] IS NULL;

        --Supply [cc]
        UPDATE #MessagesStrict
        SET [cc] = [dbo].[fnGetPrimaryEmail]([ccId])
        WHERE [cc] IS NULL
            AND [ccId] IS NOT NULL;

        --Supply [bcc]
        UPDATE #MessagesStrict
        SET [bcc] = [dbo].[fnGetPrimaryEmail]([bccId])
        WHERE [bcc] IS NULL
            AND [bccId] IS NOT NULL;

        --Format bodies with inner styling (formatBodyFlag)
        UPDATE #MessagesStrict
        SET [body] = '<div style=''a bunch of styling''>' + [body] +'</div>'
        WHERE [formatBodyFlag] = 1;

        --Declare a table to hold new MESSAGEID's
        DECLARE @MessageIds TABLE
            ([msKey] INT NOT NULL
            ,[MESSAGEID] INT NOT NULL);

        --Insert into MESSAGEQUEUE. A MERGE statement is used to allow returning columns we didn't actually insert, specifically #MessagesStrict.sortKey.
        --MySchool header and footer are also added.
        MERGE INTO [MESSAGEQUEUE]
        USING #MessagesStrict M
            ON 1 = 0 --Will never be true, so no UPDATEs will ever happen
        WHEN NOT MATCHED
            THEN
                INSERT (
                    [MESSAGESOURCE]
                    ,[SUBJECT]
                    ,[BODY]
                    ,[BODYFORMAT]
                    ,[TIMESENT]
                    ,[SENDER_EMAIL]
                    ,[PEOPLECODEID]
                    ,[HIDERECIPIENTS]
                    ,[SENDTIME]
                    ,[STATUS]
                    ,[CREATE_OPID]
                    ,[CREATE_TERMINAL]
                    ,[CREATE_DATE]
                    ,[CREATE_TIME]
                    ,[REVISION_OPID]
                    ,[REVISION_TERMINAL]
                    ,[REVISION_DATE]
                    ,[REVISION_TIME]
                    )
                VALUES (
                    ''
                    ,M.[subject]
                    ,'a bunch of styling' + M.[body] + 'a bunch more styling'
                    ,1
                    ,NULL
                    ,M.[from]
                    ,M.[fromId]
                    ,0
                    ,@Now
                    ,'N'
                    ,'SYSADMIN'
                    ,'0001'
                    ,@Today
                    ,@Now
                    ,'SYSADMIN'
                    ,'0001'
                    ,@Today
                    ,@Now
                    )
        OUTPUT M.[msKey], inserted.[MESSAGEID]
        INTO @MessageIds;

        --Associate MESSAGEIDs with #MessagesStrict
        UPDATE #MessagesStrict
        SET #MessagesStrict.[MESSAGEID] = MIDS.[MESSAGEID]
        FROM @MessageIds MIDS
        WHERE #MessagesStrict.[msKey] = MIDS.[msKey];

        ALTER TABLE #MessagesStrict ALTER COLUMN [MESSAGEID] INT NOT NULL; --A little extra validation

        --Insert [to] recipients into MESSAGERECIPIENTS
        INSERT INTO [MESSAGERECIPIENTS] (
            [MESSAGEID]
            ,[RECIPIENTTYPE]
            ,[EMAILADDRESS]
            ,[PEOPLECODEID]
            ,[CREATE_OPID]
            ,[CREATE_TERMINAL]
            ,[CREATE_DATE]
            ,[CREATE_TIME]
            ,[REVISION_OPID]
            ,[REVISION_TERMINAL]
            ,[REVISION_DATE]
            ,[REVISION_TIME]
            )
        SELECT
            M.[MESSAGEID]
            ,'to'
            ,M.[to]
            ,M.[toId]
            ,'SYSADMIN'
            ,'0001'
            ,@Today
            ,@Now
            ,'SYSADMIN'
            ,'0001'
            ,@Today
            ,@Now
        FROM #MessagesStrict M

        --Insert [cc] recipients into MESSAGERECIPIENTS
        INSERT INTO [MESSAGERECIPIENTS] (
            [MESSAGEID]
            ,[RECIPIENTTYPE]
            ,[EMAILADDRESS]
            ,[PEOPLECODEID]
            ,[CREATE_OPID]
            ,[CREATE_TERMINAL]
            ,[CREATE_DATE]
            ,[CREATE_TIME]
            ,[REVISION_OPID]
            ,[REVISION_TERMINAL]
            ,[REVISION_DATE]
            ,[REVISION_TIME]
            )
        SELECT
            M.[MESSAGEID]
            ,'cc'
            ,M.[cc]
            ,M.[ccId]
            ,'SYSADMIN'
            ,'0001'
            ,@Today
            ,@Now
            ,'SYSADMIN'
            ,'0001'
            ,@Today
            ,@Now
        FROM #MessagesStrict M
        WHERE M.[cc] IS NOT NULL

        --Insert [to] recipients into MESSAGERECIPIENTS
        INSERT INTO [MESSAGERECIPIENTS] (
            [MESSAGEID]
            ,[RECIPIENTTYPE]
            ,[EMAILADDRESS]
            ,[PEOPLECODEID]
            ,[CREATE_OPID]
            ,[CREATE_TERMINAL]
            ,[CREATE_DATE]
            ,[CREATE_TIME]
            ,[REVISION_OPID]
            ,[REVISION_TERMINAL]
            ,[REVISION_DATE]
            ,[REVISION_TIME]
            )
        SELECT
            M.[MESSAGEID]
            ,'bcc'
            ,M.[bcc]
            ,M.[bccId]
            ,'SYSADMIN'
            ,'0001'
            ,@Today
            ,@Now
            ,'SYSADMIN'
            ,'0001'
            ,@Today
            ,@Now
        FROM #MessagesStrict M
        WHERE M.[bcc] IS NOT NULL

        --Select the results as output
        SELECT
            [from]
            ,[fromId]
            ,[to]
            ,[toId]
            ,[toTypeFlag]
            ,[cc]
            ,[ccId]
            ,[bcc]
            ,[bccId]
            ,[subject]
            ,[body]
            ,[formatBodyFlag]
            ,[uniqueKey]
            ,[MESSAGEID]
        FROM #MessagesStrict;

    COMMIT TRAN MySchool_SP_SendEmails

END
```

If it would help, here's the calling SQL job. Note all the useless `SELECT NULL AS` lines. I want to make the job as easy/simple as possible to code.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON; --Stop on all errors.

BEGIN TRAN SendCancEmails

    --Select actions to process into temp table
    SELECT
        'selfservice@MySchool.edu'  [from]
        ,NULL                   [fromId]
        ,NULL                   [to]
        ,[PEOPLE_ORG_CODE_ID]   [toId]
        ,NULL                   [cc]
        ,NULL                   [ccId]
        ,NULL                   [bcc]
        ,NULL                   [bccId]
        ,0                      [toTypeFlag]
        ,AC.[ACTION_NAME]       [subject]
        ,AC.[NOTE]              [body]
        ,CASE WHEN TM.[EVENT_ID] IS NOT NULL THEN TM.[EVENT_ID] + '/' + CST.[LONG_DESC] + '/' + TM.[SECTION] + ' (' + [EVENT_LONG_NAME] + ')'
            WHEN PATINDEX('%20__/%/%/%', ACS.[ACTION_NAME]) > 0
                THEN SUBSTRING(ACS.[ACTION_NAME], CHARINDEX('/',ACS.[ACTION_NAME], CHARINDEX('/',ACS.[ACTION_NAME], 21) + 1) + 1, 100) + '...' --Try to extract section name from action name (it's often unfortunately truncated)
            ELSE '(unknown)'
            END AS              [sectionCode]
        ,1                      [formatBodyFlag]
        ,[UNIQUE_KEY]           [uniqueKey]
    INTO #Messages
    FROM [ACTIONSCHEDULE] ACS
        INNER JOIN [ACTION] AC
            ON AC.[ACTION_ID] = ACS.[ACTION_ID]
        LEFT JOIN [TRANSCRIPTMARKETING] TM
            ON TM.[PEOPLE_CODE_ID] = ACS.[PEOPLE_ORG_CODE_ID]
                AND TM.[DROP_REASON] = 'CANCEL'
                AND TM.[REVISION_DATE] = ACS.[REQUEST_DATE]
                AND TM.[REVISION_TIME] BETWEEN ([dbo].[fnMakeTime](ACS.[REQUEST_TIME]) - '00:00:05') AND ([dbo].[fnMakeTime](ACS.[REQUEST_TIME]) + '00:00:05') --Allow 10 seconds drift
        LEFT JOIN [SECTIONS] S
            ON S.[ACADEMIC_YEAR] = TM.ACADEMIC_YEAR
                AND S.ACADEMIC_TERM = TM.ACADEMIC_TERM
                AND S.ACADEMIC_SESSION = TM.ACADEMIC_SESSION
                AND S.EVENT_ID = TM.EVENT_ID
                AND S.EVENT_SUB_TYPE = TM.EVENT_SUB_TYPE
                AND S.SECTION = TM.SECTION
        LEFT JOIN CODE_EVENTSUBTYPE CST
            ON CST.CODE_VALUE = TM.EVENT_SUB_TYPE
    WHERE ACS.[ACTION_ID] = 'CANCSECT'
        AND [COMPLETED] <> 'Y'
        AND [CANCELED] <> 'Y'
        AND [WAIVED] <> 'Y';

    --Supply student names
    UPDATE M
    SET [body] = REPLACE([body], '##FIRST_NAME##', [FIRST_NAME])
    FROM #Messages AS M
        INNER JOIN PEOPLE AS P
            ON P.[PEOPLE_CODE_ID] = M.[toId];

    --Supply section names
    UPDATE #Messages
    SET [body] = REPLACE([body], '##SECTION##', [sectionCode]);

    ALTER TABLE #Messages DROP COLUMN [sectionCode];

    --Prepare table to capture results
    CREATE TABLE #MessagesResults (
        [from] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        ,[fromId] NVARCHAR(10) NULL
        ,[to] NVARCHAR(255) NULL
        ,[toId] NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
        ,[toTypeFlag] SMALLINT NOT NULL
        ,[cc] NVARCHAR(255) NULL
        ,[ccId] NVARCHAR(10) NULL
        ,[bcc] NVARCHAR(255) NULL
        ,[bccId] NVARCHAR(10) NULL
        ,[subject] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        ,[body] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
        ,[formatBodyFlag] SMALLINT NOT NULL
        ,[uniqueKey] NVARCHAR(255) NULL UNIQUE
        ,[MESSAGEID] INT NULL
        );

    --Actually send messages and capture results
    INSERT INTO #MessagesResults
    EXEC [dbo].[MySchool_SP_SendEmails];

    --Complete actions upon successful sending.
    UPDATE ACS
        SET [COMPLETED] = 'Y'
            ,[EXECUTION_DATE] = [dbo].[fnMakeDate](GETDATE())
            ,[COMPLETED_BY] = 'P000000001' --System Administrator
    FROM [ACTIONSCHEDULE] AS ACS
        INNER JOIN #MessagesResults AS MR
            ON MR.[uniqueKey] = ACS.[UNIQUE_KEY];

    DROP TABLE #Messages, #MessagesResults;

COMMIT TRAN SendCancEmails
```

Comment: where is #Messages coming from? You commented out it's creation and the insert. I don't get this error if you actually create that table and populate it. Perhaps you simply accidentally commented that out?

Comment: @scsimon I have added the calling SQL job, which creates #Messages. If using a table-valued parameter would be better please explain why - it seemed to be a lot more restrictive when I read about it.

Comment: move all that code that doesn't work to the calling proc, just under `ALTER TABLE #Messages DROP COLUMN [sectionCode];`. Wouldn't this make more sense?

Comment: @scsimon You mean all the `IF 'fromId' NOT IN...`? I suppose I could. Was trying to keep the calling job as simple as possible, as I'd like to use `MySchool_SP_SendEmails` for dozens of diverse email purposes. This whole thing should really be outside SQL, but it's a PowerBuilder environment with tons of business logic in the database. I also just want to know if it's possible to alter a temp table inside a sproc in this way.

Comment: correct. I've never seen a DDL modification outside of scope like that.